# Дублирование данных ArrayList в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, arraylist

При возврате на фрагмент, где находиться мой `RecyclerView` данные дублируются в мой `ArrayList` идентичными значениями. Не придумал ничего лучше, как в методе `onPause` очищать свою коллекцию. Считается ли такой вариант приемлемым или есть способ получше (данные могут обновиться из БД)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалить дубликаты можно таким способом:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(yourList);
yourList.clear();
yourList.addAll(set);
```

но вообще я бы проверил почему добавляются одинаковые данные. Возможно получится не крутить костыль, а решить проблему добавления дубликатов.

Comment: У меня была похожая ситуация с FragmentPagerAdapter, но решилась, когда в конструктор класса наследника вместо getFragmentManager() передал getChildFragmentManager() :) А тут коллекция и пока не знаю как поступить, только учусь)

Comment: Ну а сами данные у меня дублируются, потому что при переходе на фрагмент заново идет обращение к серверу за данными (мб что-то обновилось). Только выходит он к старым элементам добавляет полученные.